# How to call Fedex tracking number lookup Service?

Tags: java, html, fedex

Currently In my Java code we have UPS hyperlink which have some parameters including tracking number when we click on that link it takes us to UPS site where we can the status for that passed tracking number.  I want the same functionality for FedEx tracking numbers too .Is there any way I can achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass it on in query string in the URL:

```
https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&trackingnumber=[YOUR_CODE_HERE]
```

Comment: How to it the same for DHL?